# Body thrown downwards

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

I am looking for an explaination of the motion of a body thrown downwards with a force.
What will be it's acceleration? Most sources say it equals g. But suppose a body is thrown with a large force, consider a bullet fired downwards. It will have an immense acceleraiton which must be greater than g.

Answer (score 3):

Acceleration is directly related to the forces applied on an object.
During the firing of your gun, the gases from the explosion apply a force on the bullet giving it a huge acceleration **only while it is in the barrel**.

When the bullet leaves the barrel, the only force applied to it is earth's gravitational pull, and therefore its acceleration will be 9,81m/s^2, like any other object in freefall.

This is of course disregarding air resistance.

Answer (score -2):

Of course it will.U then have to add that acceleration(let's say a)with g .So ur net acceleration is (a+g).

Comment: From this can I also conclude that, considering air resistance exist, a falling body has constant gravitational acceleraiton (g) but variable acceleration (a) until it attains terminal velocity whereby it's acceleraiton becomes zero?